# problem Running Scripts on Facebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

Hey all, so I just made a small greasemonkey script for Google Chrome that should remove that annoying new photo-viewing feature facebook has added. all it Does is remove the "&theater" from the end of the URL. My first attempt was just to do that in one line.

```
if (window.location.toString().indexOf('www.facebook.com') >= 0) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/(&theater)$/, '');
}
```

But that just made the page constantly reload, executing the script over and over.
So i figured i would put that code in a function called on page load. My code now looks like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
if (window.location.toString().indexOf('www.facebook.com') >= 0) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/(&theater)$/, '');
}
}
```

My problem is that when you load a facebook page, window.onload is never called. It works for other websites, (i put an alert inside the function to check whether it was being called). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried unsafeWindow.onload = function() { }; ?

Comment: What does `alert(window.onload)` say? When I tried it on Facebook, I got back a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an endless loop of refreshing because you refresh the page even if you are on the URL you redirected to. You would be better of do an if statement like this:

```
if ((window.location.host === 'www.facebook.com') && window.location.pathname.indexOf('&theater') > -1) {
  // redirect here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are only allowed one `window.onload`, and Facebook is probably already using it?

See `alert(window.onload)`...

[image: Facebook]

Answer (score 0):

If that `onload` ***had*** worked, you'd still have an endless loop -- just longer between reloads. :)

In most situations... To avoid the loop, set a flag that survives between loads.  The easiest way to do that is to create a URL parameter.

But, in this case, you can just change what you are searching for (for now).

Something like:

```
if ( /&theater/i.test (window.location.href) )
{
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/(&theater)$/, '');
}
```